# How to choose MongoDB Connect to Cluster option?

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and I'm having some problems with MongoDB recently.

I'm not sure about Connect with the MongoDB Shell, Connect your application, Connect using MongoDB Compass, what's the difference?

The current demand is. I want to directly allow connection from anywhere and create a user account password to log into this database, which option should I choose?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwYMf.png

Answer (score 0):

1. In Connect your application tab, you get a link that you need to copy
   and paste in your application  you are building to connect it to the
   database. Remember to replace your password and databse name.
2. In Connect using MongoDB Compass tab, you get a link that you need
   to paste in your compass application(A desktop application that
   makes your mongodb data handling so much easier). And again remember to replace
   your credentials.
3. I'm not very fond of Mongodb shell. It's actually an extensible
   command-line interface.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. The problem has been solved, thank you very much for your help.